# What is the effect of putting salt on water during electrolysis

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis

I want to decompose $\ce{H}$ ion and $\ce{O}$ ion by putting carbon electrode in the water, but it look so slow. What if I put sodium chloride? Would putting $\ce{NaCl}$ have effect on output gas($\ce{H}$ and $\ce{O}$)?

Comment: If a question is asked on Chemistry SE site, then, in contrary to sites like Quora, it is expected from the author to elaborate the topic of the question by doing at least basic own topic review, writing what he/she has found and understood, and what is the stumble stone. The quick questions without explicitly expressed particular effort are not very welcome, and may be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah there is an effect putting salt during electrolysis. it give you chlorine ion at the anode which is dangerous at higher amount. in the place of sodium chloride you can use sodium hydroxide you can get it from stores it is also safe or sodium bicarbonate from baking soda.

Good luck !!

Comment: The concentration of the added sodium chloride is not specified. If small quantity of NaCl is added it will not generate chlorine at the anode i.e. no overvoltage will occur. Only in highly concentrated solutions like brine can on electrolysis generate chlorine gas at the anode, as oxygen release is kinetically hinderd.